# SQLite - Checking if time is more then one month ago

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Checking if DATETIME (TIME) is more then one month ago

This is the Update I am trying to do:

```
DELETE FROM BLOCKDATA WHERE TIME <= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE());
```

But it fails with the error:

```
No such column: month
```

The table:

```
      String sql = "CREATE TABLE BLOCKDATA " +
              " (ID    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + 
              " PLAYERID           TEXT    NOT NULL, " +
              " TIME           DATETIME    NOT NULL, " + 
              " LOCATION           TEXT    NOT NULL, " + 
              " ACTION            TEXT     NOT NULL, " + 
              " SPECIAL        TEXT, " + 
              " SPECIAL2         TEXT)";
```

I am using Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite has no DATEADD.

You have to use a modifier for one of the [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```sql
... WHERE time <= date('now', '-1 month')
```

(Which function to use depends on the actual format in the `time` column.)